# dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins

Tags: apt, dpkg

I get these error messages when I try to update or install programs on Linux 13.04

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-rb-3.0:
 gir1.2-rb-3.0 depends on librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0.1); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing gir1.2-rb-3.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 


Unpacking librhythmbox-core8 (from .../librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core7 3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0_i386.deb
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-rb-3.0:
 gir1.2-rb-3.0 depends on librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0.1); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing gir1.2-rb-3.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-mozilla:
 rhythmbox-mozilla depends on rhythmbox (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-mozilla (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 3.0); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 3.1); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0); however:
  Package librhythmbox-core8 is not installed.
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-ubuntuone:
 rhythmbox-ubuntuone depends on rhythmbox (>= 2.95.5); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
```

Hope you can help me and guide me to how to solve this problem.

Comment: The ppa you're using shows these packages for saucy, not raring. Are you on raring or saucy? In any event the 'blocker' is `librhythmbox-core7` which would need to be removed before installing the saucy packages. This could provide you some useful info as to what's up in general. `apt-cache policy *rhythmbox*`

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`.

Comment: Hi, I tried both, this are the msg I got

Comment: I get this msg: E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
kp@kp-Satellite-C660D:~$ -f
-f: command not found
kp@kp-Satellite-C660D:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
 ?????????

Comment: Hi doug, I don't know what saucy or raring is... I'm not very good at linux/ubuntu... could you give me some 'dummies' instruction... for beginners, please. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install rhythymbox` or `sudo apt-get install librhythmbox-core8` it is saying that you don't have it installed.